# Sequencial animation for dynamically added views

Tags: android, dynamic, android-animation

I'm adding views in my activity dynamically via the following function. I am generating 5 views using this function. This is working fine. My problem is when I'm applying animation to the view, all the views are getting animated. I want to animate first generated view then second and so on. Right now on the start of the activity, all 5 views are getting fade in. I already tried setStartOffset, but its not working. What should I do?

**Function for dynamical addition of views (MainActivity.java):**

```
public void addViewInActivity() {
    container.addView(addView);

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);

    final long startOffset = 1000;
    animation.setStartOffset(startOffset);

    addView.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

**fade_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="500"
        android:repeatCount="0" />
</set>
```

Comment: did you assign IDS to each views?

Comment: There is only one id to each view, But I have assigned unique tag to each view.

Comment: try to set unique ids to each view, and start first id animation, in animation end listener, start second animation...

Comment: 5 is just a number. The views are not generated by the programmer so I don't think I can add animation listeners.

Comment: then you can use Handler to delay with startOffset and start animation

Comment: Instead of applying animation on dynamically created view, you can apply animation to its ParentLayout i.e. container by using;
android:layoutAnimation="@anim/list_layout_animation"

Comment: I don't know how to do that but I'll try first. Hopefully, that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this it may help you

```
private long startOffset = 1000;

public void addViewInActivity() {
  container.addView(addView);

  Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_in);
  startOffset += 500;
  animation.setStartOffset(startOffset);

  addView.startAnimation(animation);
 }
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked flawlessly. Thanks for quick reply. Your method is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply Animation on **container**. Consider following example;

this is ParentLayout Where I am adding multiple view dynamically;

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/layoutStatus"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layoutAnimation="@anim/list_layout_animation"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:padding="10.0dip" />
```

Following is `list_layout_animation`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:animation="@anim/slide_in_right"
    android:delay="0.5" />
```

And , this is `slide_in_right`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="400"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="-100.0%"
    android:toXDelta="0.0%" />
```

Thats it.. you are ready to go!